# Unable to create new labels when making a new post using Blogger v3 API in PHP

Tags: php, curl, blogger, php-curl

I'm using the Blogger V3 API in PHP and making a new post works perfectly UNLESS I include a label that's not already on my blog. In the example below Label 1 & Label 2 already exist on my blog however Label 3 does not. When I try to process the request I get this error "(400) We're sorry, but the value for field labels was not valid." and the post is not created on my blog. If I removed Label 3 and try again the post is published with no errors. What I need to know here is has someone already come across this and found a workaround? I need to be able to add Labels 1 through 3 when making a new post. I was thinking maybe there's something I'm missing here. My blog has thousands of labels. A method where I would attempt to match the labels with ones already on my blog with a json response and add the ones that were not found isn't possible either in blogger v3 api. I'm just looking for anything that would possibly work. Please let me know if you have a workaround or any other suggestions I could try. Thanks!!

```
$blogID = 'MY_BLOG_ID';
$authToken = "MY_AUTH_TOKEN";

// The data to send to the API
$postData = array(
    'kind' => 'blogger#post',
    'blog' => array('id' => $blogID),
    'title' => 'This is a test',
    'content' => 'Testing 1 2 3...',
'labels' => array('Test1, Test2, Test3')
);

// Setup cURL
$ch = curl_init('https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/'.$blogID.'/posts/');
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_POST => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        'Authorization: OAuth '.$authToken,
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    ),
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($postData)
));

// Send the request
$response = curl_exec($ch);

// Check for errors
if($response === FALSE){
    die(curl_error($ch));
}

// Decode the response
$responseData = json_decode($response, TRUE);

// Print the date from the response
print_r($responseData);
```

> (400) We're sorry, but the value for field labels was not valid.

https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/3.0/reference/posts/insert